# Dyamic frame calculation for UIImages in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am putting few icons on UITableViewCell. The number of icons can vary from 1 to 6. Icons should not have fixed X position and instead they should be dynamically placed considering the cell space. So if there are 3 icons they should look placed centric to the cell. Also, the icon spacing should also vary. For instance when it is 6 icons all of them will be placed with less margins in between and when there are 3 then margin will be more and so will be the X position.

Please suggest some quick way to calculate this frame. I am running the app both on iOS 6 and iOS 7.

This is what I have tried by far but this does not seems to work well with icon count variation. Also, in between space is not dynamic with this.

```
int maxIconTypes = 6;

CGFloat innerPadding = ([self isIOS7]) ? 15.0f : 9.0f;
CGRect adjustedBoundsIOS6 = [self bounds];
CGFloat adjustedWidth = ([self isIOS7]) ? self.bounds.size.width : adjustedBoundsIOS6.size.width;
CGFloat xOrigin = innerPadding;
CGFloat iconViewSize = 25.0f;
CGFloat ySpacer = (self.bounds.size.height - iconSize) / 2;
CGFloat xSpacer = ((adjustedWidth - (innerPadding * 2)) - (maxRequestTypes * iconViewSize)) / (maxIconTypes - 1);

for (NSString *icon in iconList) {
    UIImageView *anIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage icon]];
    if (anIconView.image) {
                anIconView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin + originPadding, ySpacer, anIconView.image.size.width, anIconView.image.size.height);
                [self.contentView addSubview:anIconView];
                xOrigin  += anIconView.frame.size.width + xSpacer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However many items you have, the number of spaces is the same if you want equal spacing with half spacing at the start and end:

`half` `width` `full` `width` `half`

`half` `width` `full` `width` `full` `width` `half`

So, you just need to know the full width available and the combined width of the items. A simple multiply (to get the combined width of the items) and subtract (from the full width available) gives you the remaining width for the 'spacers'. Divide by the number of items to get the `xSpacer`, set the initial `xOrigin` to `xSpacer * 0.5`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what Wain is explaining:

```
//Im doing this in a UIView rather than in a UITableViewCell but idea is the same
int cellWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);

//num of icons
int iconCount = 6;

//size of icon
int iconSize = 25;

//The max padding we can have
float maxPadding = (cellWidth - (iconSize * iconCount)) / iconCount;

//Our offset
float xOrigin = maxPadding / 2;

//Loooop
for (int i = 0; i < iconCount; i++) {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, self.view.center.y, iconSize, iconSize)];

    xOrigin += (iconSize + maxPadding);

    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

Comment: @Abhinav you won't be able to drop this code in and it work. It's to show you the concept behind it. If you drop this into a the `viewDidLoad` of a blank `UIViewController` you can see it working. And it **does** work.